# Why does iteration of resultset turn into an endless loop?

Tags: php, mysql, resultset

I have a code, which so far works. However, it goes into some sort of infinite slope and keeps repeating itself without working through all the rows (30,000). I cannot figure out how to cycle through each row once at the time!

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');

if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("", $con);

$sql="SELECT prodName,merchant FROM `affiliSt_products1`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $merchant = $row[merchant];
    mysql_query("UPDATE affiliSt_products1 SET prodName = CONCAT(prodName,' By $merchant') WHERE merchant = '$merchant' ") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

The above is to make the search much more effective. Will make it easy to locate a merchant only product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy, just change [`fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/it/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) to [`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) and it should work fine!

Answer (score 0):

Just do the whole thing with a single `UPDATE` statement:

```sql
UPDATE affiliSt_products1 SET prodName = CONCAT(prodName,' By ', merchant)
```

Answer (score 0):

change 
`while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))`